# Is there a way to generate a "select none" Button in a DT::datatable() without shiny?

Tags: r, dt

I'm trying to get a selectNone button into my DT::datatable() to deselect all selected items in the table (https://datatables.net/reference/button/selectNone).

I tried to implement it, but it did not work:

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris,
          extensions = 'Buttons',
          options = list(
            dom = 'Bfrtip',
            buttons = list(
              "copy",
              list(
                extend = "select_none",
                text = 'Select none',
                action = DT::JS("function () {",
                                "table.rows().deselect();",
                                "}")
              )
            )
          )
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris,
          extensions = c("Buttons", "Select"),
          options = list(
            dom = 'Bfrtip',
            select = TRUE, 
            buttons = list(
              "copy", "selectNone"
            )
          )
)
```

If you want to change the label of the button:

```
datatable(iris,
          extensions = c("Buttons", "Select"),
          options = list(
            dom = 'Bfrtip',
            select = TRUE, 
            buttons = list(
              "copy",
              list(
                extend = "selectNone",
                text = "Select none"
              )
            )
          )
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works perfectly! My hope was that this also works with the crosstalk package (e.g. DT + plotly scatter plot). But the de-selection has no impact on the plot. Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: I do have the same issue. Did you get an answer ? thanks !